# 10.5 clients cannot connect via AFP to OS X 10.4.11 server

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, file-sharing, afp

Server : xServe running 10.4.11

Login with AFP is successful with

Clients:

all 10.6.x
all 10.4.x

Login fails ( or more accurately never produces a login dialog window,
just get a "Connecting to afp://x.x.x.x" message with barber pole
progress bar ) with any 10.5.x client ( workstation or server )
There is another 10.4.11 server in this network that allows 10.4, 10.6
and 10.5 clients to connect without issues.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try to connect to server from command line, it will produce more likely an error code.

```
sudo mount -t afp afp://user:pass@_server_ip_address/share /Volumes/share
```

/Volumws/share must exists before

Alternative method:

`sudo mount_afp afp://user:pass.@_server_ip_address/share /Volumes/share`

Comment: I can't seem to get that command to work on OS X AFP servers here that don't seem to have this particular issue either. I tried 'man' mount_afp to no avial. Thanks though.

Comment: I added an alternative method using mount_afp

Answer (score 2):

I'd check each servers settings as to what forms of authentication are permitted. Use Server Admin to look at the settings in the AFP section each server.

Comment: Authentication is set for "Any" ( Standard or Kerberos ) on all the AFP servers.